# Set a default value for the jQuery daterangepicker by Filament

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to set the value of a daterangepicker field programmatically? How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a text input, so yes, you can set it.

On Filament's [example page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/), you could do the following:

```
$('input').val('08/10/2010');
```

Additionally, an excerpt from Filament group's [date range picker page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/):

> Driven by Input Value
>
> The datepickers will be generated
>   based on any values that are in the
>   inputs at page load. For single
>   inputs, it will split the input value
>   by the rangeSplitter character
>   (default: '-'). Each value is parsed
>   by date.js, so you could even begin
>   with a range like "today - next week"
>   in the input, and the datepickers will
>   be set accordingly.

Comment: absolutely perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found daterangepicker ( http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/ ) and am trying to customize it.

Selected should be shown by orange highlighting

Week - Select the current week from Sunday to Saturday and then allows the user to select any other week range where Sunday to Saturday will be selected

Month - Select the entire current month and then allows the user to flip months where the entire month block is selected.